# Keep scroll-position on ajax-request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an **one-page website** with a lot of containers.

The **content of each container is loaded via ajax** (asynchron, means not every container is filled with data at the same time).

The containers have a **dynamic height** (height: auto).

The website is controlled with an **intelligent routing system** (if you enter a specific url, the website scrolls to the given element on load).

How can I scroll to a container (for example container 5) and **keep this container on the same scroll-position** (should be changable by user-scrolling) while the other containers are loading? If the containers have a fixed height, the whole thing works without any problems but at the moment, the scroll-position changes on every load or change of any of those containers.

Do you know a plugin or a good way to resolve this problem?

Example of the problem: [http://jsfiddle.net/b6sno9cv/](http://jsfiddle.net/b6sno9cv/1/)

```
// Global variable to define start-container:
var initialWidgetIdx = 10;
```

**Expected result:**

Scroll to container 10 and stay there (scroll-position on this container), even if the other containers are not completly loaded.

(Once every container is loaded (has fixed height now), the scroll works without any problem)

Comment: Could you limit the height of the containers, then user `overflow: scroll` so that users can scroll within each container to see all of the content?

Comment: This is not possible, the containers must have a dynamic height.

Comment: Well, have you considered adding width and height attributes to the images in containers 1-9, like the spec recommended?

Comment: Then I think you will just have to wait until all of the content is rendered before you scroll. It's impossible to know what the height will be ahead of time, especially since it can vary so much based on browser, screen size, etc.

Comment: @Brian even if I'm doing this, the content is loaded via Ajax and has not allways the same size...

Comment: @SteveSanders hm, this is sad... it may take up to 10secs to load the complete website and if I wait with scroll until then, it looks horrible

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `offsetHeight` to get the height of the element. In your case, you can check the height of the div in your ajax request and then use `scrollBy`, like this

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4) return
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            //do some stuff you need

            var scroll_value = document.getElementById('div_that_loaded').offsetHeight();
            window.scrollBy(0,scroll_value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hm, interesting idea... is it possible to show a fixed height and other content while loading the whole content of the container in the background (images and other elements) and once the whole content is loaded, displaying it and reseting the scroll position? And if yes, how can I do this (just the waiting stuff, the other things I'm able to do myself)?

Comment: @JakeParis yes, his "solution" isn't working but if you invert the scroll_value variable it may work, or am I wrong?

Comment: I believe you have one function that do ajax, so the window will be scrolled each time the div is loaded?

Comment: Yes, I have a function that does ajax-request (event with a callback) but the window is just scrolled once by JS and this is on page load...

Comment: The idea is to get the height of every div as soon as it's fully loaded, so we know how much we need to scroll down. If your divs have some initial height you just need to improve `scroll_value`

Comment: It can take up to 10 seconds until every div is fully loaded and I cant wait until then to scroll...

Comment: And if you put `scrollBy` in an ajax request it works only once? huh. Then i have no more ideas. However, if you'll manage to make this work, you should also check if loaded div is lower than current, and that's not easy i think